# For looping in Pascal

Tags: for-loop, logic, pascal, freepascal

## Can you explain this code?

```
program exercise1;
uses crt;
var
    x,y,z,i,j,k,temp : integer;
begin
    clrscr;
    write('input x: ');readln(x);
    write('input y: ');readln(y);
    write('input z: ');readln(z);

    for i:= 1 to x do            { (1 x 1 x 1) = 1 and (2 x 2 x 2) = 8 }
        for j:= 2 to y do        { (1 x 2 x 2) = 4                     }
            for k:= 1 to z do    { (1 x 1 x 1) = 1 and (1 x 1 x 2) = 2 }
                temp:= temp+(i*j*k);
    writeln(temp);               { should be 14, but is 18 instead     }
    readln;
end.
```

My understanding is like this:

1. If we input `x`, `y` and `z` with values `2`, `2` and `2` the output will be `18`.
2. In the `for` variable `k` the first looping is **(1 x 1 x 1) = 1** and for the second looping it is **(1 x 1 x 2) = 2**.
3. In the `for` variable `j` it is **(1 x 2 x 2) = 4**.
4. In the `for` variable `i` it is **(1 x 1 x 1) = 1** and for the second looping it is **(2 x 2 x 2) = 8**.

But the sum (**2 + 4 + 8**) should be `14` - please help with the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly recommend the initialization of `temp` to 0, the subsequent reasoning will assume that the initial value of `temp` was 0.

`x`, `y` and `z` are user-defined values.

- `i` is looping from 1 to `x`
- `j` is looping from 2 to `y`
- `k` is looping from 1 to `z`

Each time their product is added to `temp`.

## x=2, y=2, z=2

- `i` is 1

  - `j` is 2

    - `k` is 1

      - we add 1 * 2 * 1 = 2 to `temp`, resulting in 2
    - `k` is 2

      - we add 1 * 2 * 2 = 4 to `temp`, resulting in 2 + 4 = 6
- `i` is 2

  - `j` is 2

    - `k` is 1

      - we add 2 * 2 * 1 = 4 to `temp`, resulting in 6 + 4 = 10
    - `k` is 2

      - we add 2 * 2 * 2 = 8 to `temp`, resulting in 10 + 8 = 18

## The mistake in your calculation

You have missed the case of (2 x 2 x 1), this is why you reached 14 instead of 18. In order to analyze problems such as this one, it is recommendable to either take a pen & paper and go through it step-by-step, or debug your code using a [debugger](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userch10.html).

Comment: @TomBrunberg Looked into it at https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse24.html, it turns out you are right. I have edited my answer. Thanks for making that point!

Comment: Well, temp is also not guaranteed zero initialized in Pascal. (object pascal is a bit more complicated). So not setting temp to zero is a bug, even though it works because you run a compiler with an RTL that also does object pascal.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort "Global variables are initialized with the equivalent of zero." (source: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse24.html). According to the quote, variables are defaulted to the equivalent of 0. Can you point out why is `temp` in this example a different scenario?